# VBA code for copying and pasting the most up to date data from a file on a share drive into a master

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I'm curious about how to write a macro to sequentially pick up the most up to date file based on date ...

I have written a macro to copy and paste data from a file located on a share drive into a master but now need to alter it so that it picks up the most up to date excel file. I have named my files in the following format "20160411"

Any ideas?

I realize this may be a vague post so I am going to try to explain in further detail.

this is the code i currently have:

```
Sub PullFromFile()

Dim wkb As Workbook, wkbFrom As Workbook

Set wkb = ThisWorkbook '-> assuming the workbook you want to copy to has code in it
Set wkbFrom = Workbooks.Open("\\drive\folder\PRICING\file name\file name \2016\20160411.xls")

Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = wkbFrom.Sheets("Ratesheet")

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = wks.Rows("7:2000")  '-> set your specific rows, here

rng.Copy wkb.Sheets("Ratesheet Current").Range("A7") '-> adjust to your settings

wkbFrom.Close False

End Sub
```

Comment: for your code please use ctrl-K on it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean you'd like to loop through the files in a given director, all of which have a filename of "yyyymmdd", and select the most recent filename... You could use the `Dir` function for your loop, the `DateSerial` function to convert the filename to a date and then take the most recent. Code would look as follows (but you'd need some error handling to avoid rogue filenames or workbooks entering the path folder):

```
Sub RunMe()
    Dim path As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim dd As Integer
    Dim mm As Integer
    Dim yyyy As Integer
    Dim dat As Date
    Dim latest As Date
    Dim wkb As Workbook

    path = "[Your path goes here]"
    fileName = Dir(path & "\*.xls")
    Do Until fileName = vbNullString
        yyyy = Int(Left(fileName, 4))
        mm = Int(Mid(fileName, 5, 2))
        dd = Int(Mid(fileName, 7, 2))
        dat = DateSerial(yyyy, mm, dd)
        If dat > latest Then dat = latest
        fileName = Dir()
    Loop
    fileName = Format(dat, "yyyymmdd") & ".xls"
    Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(path & "\" & fileName)
End Sub
```

Comment: In order to run this do i paste it above my existing code and just add my file path in the "[Your path goes here]" section ? @Ambie

Comment: @SamuelLeak, yes and the path will look something like "c:\docs\abc". To run it place your cursor inside the routine and hit F5. However, if you need to ask that type of question you might want to do a bit of reading on VBA first (not loads, just the basics) otherwise you're just pasting unknown code into your projects.